# tf.estimator Error: ResourceExhausted: too many open files (TF keeps events.out.tfevents files open)

Tags: tensorflow

I get the following error after several calls to `train_model` in the class below:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable`

I want to be able to call `train_model` multiple times with fixed `num_steps` and different `model_dir` after instantiating the class.

*(I think there is a memory leak somewhere but I could not find out what is causing it (the GPU memory usage does not change after each call to `train_model`, but RAM usage increases slightly after each call. When I get the error I still have a lot of RAM and GPU memory available on the machine.)* --> **Update**: It was not a memory leak but opening too many files

## Update:

I ran this on a different machine and the error is more clear: **ResourceExhausted: Too many open files**

I looked at `lsof` and noticed that the TF keeps `events.out.tfevents` files open after each call to `train_model` with a different checkpoint directory. Any idea how to close the `events.out.tfevents` files after calling tf.estimator?

Here is my code (a simple FeedForward NN with dropout and batch normalization for classification):

```
class Model:
def __init__(self):
    self.data_loaded = False
    self.train_data = None
    self.valid_data = None
    print('class created!')


def input_fn(self, mode, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
    if mode == 'train':
        features_cont = self.data_dict['x_train_cont']
        features_cat = self.data_dict['x_train_cat']
        labels = self.data_dict['y_train']
    elif mode == 'valid':
        features_cont = self.data_dict['x_valid_cont']
        features_cat = self.data_dict['x_valid_cat']
        labels = self.data_dict['y_valid']
        num_epochs = 1
    elif mode == 'test':
        features_cont = self.data_dict['x_test_cont']
        features_cat = self.data_dict['x_test_cat']
        labels = np.zeros([features_cont.shape[0], 1])
        num_epochs = 1

    features = np.concatenate([features_cont, features_cat], axis=1)

    shuffle = mode == 'train'

    return tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(features, labels,
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                              shuffle=shuffle)


def model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, params):
    is_training = mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    # concat cont and cat features
    l2_weights = params['l2_w']
    dropout_rates = params['dropout']
    n_classes = 2  # binary classification
    x_in = features #tf.concat(features, axis=1)
    hidden_layer = x_in

    for i, num_units in enumerate(params['num_units']):
        hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden_layer,
                                         units=num_units,
                                         name='hidden_{}'.format(i),
                                         kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=l2_weights[i]))

        hidden_layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(hidden_layer, training=is_training)

        hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer)

        hidden_layer = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=hidden_layer,
                                         rate=dropout_rates[i],
                                         name='hidden_drop_{}'.format(i),
                                         training=is_training)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden_layer,
                             units=n_classes,
                             name='output')

    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='probability_predictions')

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,
                                          predictions={'predictions': predictions},
                                          # export_outputs=export_outputs
                                          )

    weights = tf.gather(tf.constant(self.class_weights), tf.cast(labels[:, 1], tf.int32))
    l2_loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits, weights) + l2_loss

    auc = tf.metrics.auc(labels[:, 1], predictions[:, 1])
    eval_metric_ops = {'auc': auc}

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss,
                                          eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    # needed for batch norm layer
    extra_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params['learning_rate'], epsilon=1e-07)
    with tf.control_dependencies(extra_ops):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    # Set logging hook for tf.estimator
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({'step': global_step,
                                               'loss': loss,
                                               #'auc': auc[1]
                                               },
                                              every_n_iter=1)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op,
                                      training_hooks=[logging_hook])

def train_model(self, hps, model_dir=None, num_steps=None):
    max_steps = None
    num_epochs = None
    # get TF logger
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    if not os.path.exists(model_dir):
        os.makedirs(model_dir)
    self.setup_tf_logger(model_dir)
    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                            log_device_placement=False)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        save_checkpoints_steps=1e10,
        keep_checkpoint_max=1,
        model_dir=model_dir,
        session_config=config
    )
    batch_size = hps['batch_size']

    if self.train_data is None:
        self.train_data =  self.input_fn(mode='train',
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           num_epochs=num_epochs)
        self.valid_data =  self.input_fn(mode='valid',
                                           batch_size=100000,
                                           num_epochs=1)

    model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=self.model_fn,
                                   params=hps,
                                   config=run_config)
    model.train(input_fn=self.train_data,
                steps=num_steps,
                max_steps=None)
    eval_out = model.evaluate(input_fn=self.valid_data)
    return eval_out['auc']
```

## Update 2:

I had to change the TF code to address this issue. 
Currently in `basic_session_run_hooks.py` and `estimator.py` `flush()` is called on the summary writer which only dumps the data but does not close the file.

I changed this calls on the summary writer to `close()` instead of `flush()`. The files seem to be closed after the call to the tf.estimator and I no longer get a ResourceExhausted error.

There must be a reason (probably the cost of opening and closing files) that tensorflow team used `flush()` instead of `close()` on the summary writer, but this can lead to issues similar to what I reported here.