# Tensorflow opens files but doesn't close them

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having problems with getting tensorflow to test multiple DNNClassifiers with pandas dataframes.  The error I'm recieving is `ResourceExhaustedError ... Too many open files`. I tried using `del` along with `gc.collect()` to get tensorflow to close the files, but that hasn't resolved the issue. An answer to a previous question, [tf.estimator Error: ResourceExhausted: too many open files (TF keeps events.out.tfevents files open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956551/tf-estimator-error-resourceexhausted-too-many-open-files-tf-keeps-events-out), involved editing tensorflow itself to make it work, but I am not able to edit tensorflow in my current environment.  The code that causes the error is below.

```
(df,featurecolumns) = create_df('r')
(testdf,testfeaturecolumns) = create_df('r9')
x = 1
y = 1
maxunits = 100
maxaccuracy = 0.0
bestunits = [0,0]

testbar = Bar("Testing models: ", max = maxunits*maxunits)
while x <= maxunits:
    y = 1
    while y <= maxunits:
        dnnclassifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=featurecolumns, hidden_units=[x,y])
        dnnclassifier.train(input_fn=pd_input_fn(df,'flag'))
        dnnclassifierresults = dnnclassifier.evaluate(input_fn=pd_input_fn(testdf,'flag'))
        if dnnclassifierresults['accuracy'] > maxaccuracy:
            maxaccuracy = dnnclassifierresults['accuracy']
            bestunits = [x,y]
         y = y + 1
         del dnnclassifier
         del dnnclassifierresults
         gc.collect()
         testbar.next()
    x = x + 1
    testbar.next()
testbar.finish()
print("Best Parameters: " + str(bestunits) + " units with " + str(maxaccuracy*100) + "% accuracy.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) and run the logic in a new process, so when the process ends all related resources are released. Something like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class TestNetworkProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, x, y):  # add other parameters
        super(mp.Process, self).__init__()  # don't forget
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def run(self):
        # your code here, e.g.
        dnnclassifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[x,y])
        self.accuracy = dnnclassifierresults['accuracy']


# initialization code
best_accuracy, best_xy = 0.0, None
for x in range(1, 100):
    for y in range(1, 100):
        proc = TestNetworkProcess(x, y)
        proc.start()
        proc.join()

        if proc.accuracy > best_accuracy:
            best_accuracy, best_xy = proc.accuracy, (x, y)
```

Modify the code to pass the training and testing data, etc. Python processes use copy-on-write, so you can pass the pandas dataframes in the `__init__` without reloading them every time.